# Simple extension of boost::archive::text_oarchive

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I am trying to add a member variable to a Boost archive class. Following [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/serialization/doc/derivation.html), I came up with:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class MyOArchive : public boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<MyOArchive>
{
public:
    bool MyData;

    friend class boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<MyOArchive>;
    friend class basic_text_oarchive<MyOArchive>;
    //friend class boost::serialization::save_access; // save_access in namespace boost::serialization does not name a type

    MyOArchive(std::ostream& os, unsigned int flags = 0) : boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<MyOArchive>(os, flags) {}

};

class MyClass
{
public:

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    double Value;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & Value;
    }

};


int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    //boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    MyOArchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive << myClass;
    outputStream.close();

    return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting linker errors:

`undefined reference to boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<MyOArchive>::text_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&, unsigned int)`

Can anyone explain what is going wrong here? I don't need to reimplement any of the functions of the archive, just attach this member `MyData`.

Comment: Can you make the sample self contained? I remember seeing subtle problems like this when my boost library was compiled with different version of GCC. But I don't recall the specifics. If you post a self contained example that exhibits the problem for you, I can try to reproduce the linker error.

Comment: @sehe This example is self contained, no? Note that it links fine if I switch to the standard archive  class included in Boost.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Some how I missed a part when I scrolled through it the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah. Spotted it.

You need to include the `ipp`s for the basic implementations in exactly one TU that's linked into the end product.

```
#include <boost/archive/impl/basic_text_oarchive.ipp>
#include <boost/archive/impl/text_oarchive_impl.ipp>
```

Also, `save_access` lives in a different <strike>castle</strike> namespace:

```
friend class boost::archive::save_access;
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/892c79f31875c592)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/impl/basic_text_oarchive.ipp>
#include <boost/archive/impl/text_oarchive_impl.ipp>
#include <fstream>

class MyOArchive : public boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<MyOArchive> {
  public:
    bool MyData;

    friend class boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<MyOArchive>;
    friend class basic_text_oarchive<MyOArchive>;
    friend class boost::archive::save_access;

    MyOArchive(std::ostream &os, unsigned int flags = 0) : boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<MyOArchive>(os, flags) {}
};

class MyClass {
  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    double Value;

    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) { ar &Value; }
};

int main() {
    MyClass myClass;

    {
        std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");

        MyOArchive outputArchive(outputStream);
        outputArchive << myClass;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
22 serialization::archive 13 0 0 6.95328877045326431e-310
```

Comment: Yep, that does it! It actually seems that none of the three friend class declarations in MyOArchive are required for this to compile+link?

Comment: Friend declarations are effectively forward declarations. If undeclared, they will be considered as being declared in the enclosing namespace. The type will /just/ be an incomplete type until the definition is seen by the compiler.