# faild to link boost::serialization with Clion and CMAKE

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-serialization

Im trying to link my code with the boost::serialization library but I'm getting `undefined reference` errors:

```
CMakeFiles/shared_memory.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:93: undefined reference to `boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/shared_memory.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `void boost::archive::load_access::load_primitive<boost::archive::text_iarchive, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(boost::archive::text_iarchive&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:108: undefined reference to `boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::load(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [shared_memory] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/shared_memory.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/shared_memory.dir/rule] Error 2
```

this is my cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(shared_memory)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS  "-lrt")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}")

find_package(Threads)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
find_package(Boost 1.75.0 COMPONENTS date_time serialization system)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    message("Boost found")
    include_directories(interprocess ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(shared_memory ${SOURCE_FILES} )
    target_link_libraries(shared_memory ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

I have the serialization bin files.
I also check if the libs ware build using 32 or 64 bit but its look like it 64

```
file libboost_wserialization.so.1.75.0
libboost_wserialization.so.1.75.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=2a7684c9676aa222efc3a90d83f8d28b8a09bd0e, not stripped
[yaodav@localhost lib]$ file libboost_serialization.so.1.75.0
libboost_serialization.so.1.75.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=18e3423f8353dd5c29c684c9521875dcb8b6c6bf, not stripped
```

Comment: You're missing some `boost::archive` include files in your project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple extension of boost::archive::text\_oarchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936129/simple-extension-of-boostarchivetext-oarchive)

Comment: @Corristo part of it, know Im getting `home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/shared_memory/cmake-build-debug/shared_memory: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_date_time.so.1.75.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` even though my CMAKE gives my this message: `Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.75.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.75.0", minimum required is "1.75.0") found components: date_time serialization system 
Boost found`

Comment: I suspect that CMake doesn't set the build-RPATH correctly because it doesn't realize that `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` contains paths to libraries. Can you try `target_link_libraries(shared_memory PRIVATE ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} Boost::date_time Boost::serialization Boost::system)` instead? If you use that version you can also get rid of the call of `include_directories` as CMake will automatically add the Boost libraries' include paths.

Comment: @Corristo the same

Comment: What's the output of `objdump -x /home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/shared_memory/cmake-build-debug/shared_memory | grep -E 'RPATH|RUNPATH'`?

Comment: @Corristo where to run it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229220/discussion-between-corristo-and-yaodav).